# Firebase Cloud HTTP Message from Web

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up a webpage (home.html) that a user can sign into firebase using authentication. Once they authenticate, they are directed to a new page(test.html). Once they are here, I want to be able to send a notification or data message.

I am wondering if anyone can help me with the code to send a notification - any type of notification. I've been on this for 3 days and cannot send a notification from the web!! I can't find any tutorials on this - only people using curls.

I have no idea how to handle the code below, which is supposed to be on how to send a notification to the devices subscribed to a topic. I am guessing that this is all JSON and needs to be put into a JSON object?

Please assume the Initialization is filled in, I removed all info - even though I think that information is supposed to be public.

[image]

Thanks for any info!

This is my service worker (so far): firebase-messaging.sw.js

```
  // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
  // Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
  // are not available in the service worker.
  importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-app.js');
  importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-messaging.js');  

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
    const title = "Hello World";
    const options = {
      body: payload.data.status
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
  });
```

This is the app.js file that goes to the test.html page

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token){
    console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  })

  messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
    console.log('onMessage:', payload);
  });
```

And the barebones test.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually one should not send push notification from client side.. I mean why do you wanna share you FCM token to public? 
Use cloud functions if you don't wanna make a server for push notifications

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary I am completely new to web dev, so i'm not quite on the level I need to be. I don't want to share my FCM token to the public, i'm just not sure about the interaction between client/server/client here. Am I interacting with my hosting server, or google's cloud server? If it's google's server, how do I get my client to send a message to their server to pass along?

Comment: In that case you might wanna look at firebase functions. One can make an http endpoint which will accept request payload containing your message and then will call FCM to send message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Himanshu Chaudhary said. It is not a good practice to push notification from client to client. People when accesing your token, could missuse the notifications. But this beeing said, if you really really want to do that. lets say for testing porpuse, private project ... it is simply a http post from the second client (or better the server) to the client which had enabled the notifications:

```
var option = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    Authorization: "key=AAAAnww...", // your Firebase cloud messaging Server key 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "notification": {
      "title": "some tilte:",
      "body": "more text",
      "icon": "./src/assets/favicons/logo.png",
      "click_action": deepLinkUrl
    },
    "to": token // the token from 'messaging.getToken(' from the reciving client
  }),
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default'
};
fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', option);
```

Comment: I would truly rather have my web client send a message to the google cloud servers, so that they can pass the message along. All I ever see in the documentation is that above image, so I was trying to do the best I could with the little understanding that I had. Is there a way to pass a message to the google server so that they can pass the message to the clients?

Comment: you could send the http post message from the client to the fcm server. The code that i provided does exactly that. in case your supporting browsers don't support all the `fetch` api, you could of course replace it with the good old `XMLHttpRequest ` or `$.post`.

Comment: I will test the above code and get back with you before the bounty expires.

Comment: As a head's up, almost everything now supports fetch. The only browser that doesn't have any support is Opera.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


class Sender{

private $to;
private $is_background;
private $title ; 
private $message;
private $image;
private $fullcontent  ;
//private $payload;
//private $timestamp;

//Firebase cloud messaging Server key 
public $firebase_sever_token = "AAAAUccflps:APA91bF...." ; 


  public function __construct ( $title, $message) {
    $this->to = '/topics/global' ; 
    $this->is_background = false;
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->message = $this->ShortenMessage($message);
    $this->fullcontent = $message;

  }


public function sendNotifications(){

        $payload = array();
        $payload['title'] = $this->title ;
        $payload['fullMessage'] = $this->fullcontent;


        $res = array();
        $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
        $res['data']['is_background'] = $this->is_background ;
        $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
        $res['data']['image'] = ""; 
        $res['data']['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        $res['data']['payload'] = $payload ; 


        $fields = array(
            'to' => $this->to,
            'data' => $res,
        );

        $this->sendPushNotification($fields,$this->firebase_sever_token) ; 

}






    public function ShortenMessage($message){
    $string = strip_tags($message);

        if (strlen($string) > 100) {


            $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 80);
            return  $stringCut." ..." ;
        }

    return $string;

    }


    public function sendPushNotification($fields,$firebase_sever_token) {


        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';


        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $firebase_sever_token,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($result) ;
      //  return $result;
    }

}
```

and to execute the object from that class

```
$sender = new Sender($title, $Content);
$sender -> sendNotifications();
```